# Can't properly transfer data from a class in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple game

What will happen is a player will be hit by various objects that result in increase/ decrease of health

The mainGame(); is created just to see if its working properly.

On compilation i get this

```
(.text$_ZN5gamer7setDataEv[__ZN5gamer7setDataEv]+0x117)||undefined reference to `gamer::mainGame()'|
```

I tried the `friend` keyword but that gave me the error of undefined reference to object

```
class gamer
{
public:
    string gName;
    int gHealth;
    int continueGame;
    void mainGame();

    void setData()
    {

        cout << "Enter your name " <<endl;
        cin >> gName;

        srand(time(0));

        gHealth = 100 + (rand()%200);

        cout << gName << " has health of " << gHealth << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to continue ? 0 for yes" << endl;
        cin >> continueGame;

        if (continueGame == 0)
        {
            mainGame();
        }
    }
};

void mainGame()
    {
        gamer gamer;
        while(gamer.gHealth >= 0 || gamer.gHealth <= 500)
        {
            cout << " aaaaaa" << endl;
            gamer.gHealth -= 50;
            cout << gamer.gHealth << endl ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should be `void gamer::mainGame()`.

Comment: @KenY-N, I am new to this.  Could you guide me as to which line should be modified ?

Comment: first I would strongly discourage you to use `using namespace std`. this namespace is so huge you will run into problems with several names. second you should NOT name your variable exactly the same as your class. which could be one of your problems

Comment: The declaration of `void mainGame()` must be `void gamer::mainGame()`. So the compiler knows, that is a definition of this function and not some free function.

Comment: @churill Derror: extra qualification 'gamer::' on member 'mainGame' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: @skratchi.at I tried diffrent name too. But that made no diffrence

Comment: @skratchi.at error: aggregate 'gamer gamer1' has incomplete type and cannot be defined|.

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code The answer given, will point you to the problem =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **declared** the `mainGame` function as a member of your `gamer` class but never actually **defined it**. You came close, but forgot to declare, in the definition, that it a member of the class. The below should work:

```cpp
void gamer::mainGame() // This is a member function of `gamer`, so declare it as such!
    {
    //  gamer gamer; // We don't need this reference, as the member function will have...
        while(gHealth >= 0 || gHealth <= 500) // ... an implied "this" object when called
        {
            cout << " aaaaaa" << endl;
            gHealth -= 50; // Just using the member name on its own is enough to get it.
            cout << gHealth << endl ;
        }
    }
```

Inside a member function, you don't need code declaring an object of that class! When the function is called (by an object of the class) the function effectively receives a pointer to the object that called it; you can *explicitly* access this pointer with the `this` keyword but, generally, you don't need to. Just using the name of a member variable in that function will reference that member variable for the object that called the function.

Comment: After the changes and protyping the function in class, it gives me this error.   |error: extra qualification 'gamer::' on member 'mainGame' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: After editing it back to void gamer(); the program runs but seems to be on an infinite loop

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code Yes - if you put the definition inside the class declaration (a so-called 'in-body' definition) then you don't need the `gamer::` part. This is common practice for small (one or two lines) functions but, for larger member functions, it is more usual to have them declared in the class but defined outside (in which case you *must* have the `gamer:::` qualifier. Make sense?